# Access standard php file path within Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project that is using Laravel, and I want to add the fullcalendar plugin to it. I just want to be able to navigate through the calendar folder as if it wasn't using laravel views etc.

I've created a separate folder in the root directory called "calendar" which has a file "index.php" so the url I would like to access this from would be "{WEBSITENAME}/calendar.index.php"

I'm quite novice with Laravel so I'm not sure how to do this, I've tried to find some similar questions here and I found one suggesting to modify the htaccess file, so I've got htaccess within the "calendar" folder which reads

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

But whenever I try access "{WEBSITENAME}/calendar/index.php" it gives me the generic "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH." which is the Laravel view checker?

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Laravel files are served from the `public/` folder. Is `/calendar.index.php` a typo? `/calendar/index.php`

Comment: Yes sorry will update that, /calendar/index.php is correct.

Comment: I added this to my public htaccess file - "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/calendar" but it's still not letting me access the calendar folder. I also added calendar to the public folder (not sure if this makes a difference or not)